# CSS Media Query only works on browser resize (Chrome)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, window-resize

I have a website that has media queries for responsiveness. The CSS works just fine on Firefox and IE, but not on Chrome.

Currently, the website has two floating divs, as the viewport width decreases, the divs stack on top of each other. (I have a 'large mode' and a 'small mode').

My problem is that the second div should be `top:20%` when in 'large mode' - this works in Firefox and IE, but only works in Chrome if I resize the browser. It's like Chrome ignores the `top:20%` when the page first loads.

This is my CSS currently (excuse me if it is not perfect, I am only a learning high-school student):

```css
 body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
 }
 
 div{
  height:90vh;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 }
 
 #sectionone {
  background-color:#AB3E5B;
  padding-top:3%;
  padding-left:20%;
  padding-right:20%;
  padding-bottom:0;
  margin:auto;
  }
  
 #sectiontwo {
  text-align:center;
  padding-top: 10%;
  font-size:3.5vh;
  color:#666666;
  
 }
 
 #sectionthree {
  background-color:#AB3E5B;
  
 }
 
 #scrolldownimage {
  bottom:10%;
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-6mm;
  max-width:73px;
  min-width:40px;

 }
 
 /* WHEN IN SMALL MODE */
 
 @media screen and (max-width: 300mm) {
 
 #herophone {
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:55vh;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
 }


 #onea {

  float:left;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  text-align:center;
  max-height:80%;
  
  


 }
 
 #oneb {

  height:auto;
  width:100%;
  max-height:80%;
  font-size:3.5vh;
  text-align:center; 
  color: white;
  position: relative;


 }
 }
 
 /* WHEN IN LARGE MODE */
 
 
 @media screen and (min-width: 300mm) {
   #onea {
     width:45%;
     height:80%;
   float:left;
     text-align:center;
     display: block;
     justify-content: center;
     

   
    }
    
    #oneb { 
  width:45%;   
  height: 80%;
  float:right;
  font-size:5vh;
  top:20%;
  

  max-height:80%;
  text-align:center; 
  color: white;
  position: relative;


  

  
  }
  
  #herophone {
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  
  }
  
 }
```

```html
<head>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="styles.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
   
  <div id="sectionone">
        
            <div id="onea">
            
            <img src="images/Three - Small.png" height="auto" width="auto" alt="screenshot" id="herophone">
            
            </div>
            
            <div id="oneb">
            
            store maps
            <br>
   in your pocket.
            <br>
            <br>
   meet wai
            <br>
   <span style="font-size:2vh"> (where am i)</span>
            
            </div>
      
        


        
        <br>
        
        
        
  <p>
        <a data-scroll data-options='{"easing":"easeOutQuad"}' href="#sectiontwo">
        <img src="images/down.png" alt="down" width="10mm" height="auto" id="scrolldownimage">
        </a>
        </p>
        
        </div>
        
        
  <div id="sectiontwo">
        
        WAI (Where am I) is a phone app that has been developed to make shopping easier.
        
        <br>
        <br>
        
        Get instant access store maps of some of Australia's leading shopping centres.
        
        <br>
        <br>
        
        
        
        </div>
        
        
<div id="sectionthree">
       
       </div>
        
</body>

<!-- Scroll Script -->
<script src="scroll/dist/js/smooth-scroll.js"></script>
<script>
    smoothScroll.init();
</script>
```

Comment: The design works in the CODE SNIPPET above, but does not work when opened properly in Chrome.

Comment: Works in chrome for me: http://jsfiddle.net/b52ymjkn/

Comment: any actual links that we can preview?

Comment: http://wai.x10.mx/index.html
(Works in Firefox but not Chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue.

There was conflicting CSS:
The `top:20%` was interfering with a button (image) that was set to `bottom:10%`

So I put the button in a seperate `div`